# Xpath selector, select an element depending of innertext of its childs

Tags: html, xpath

I have this html :

```
<tbody>
    <tr id="1">
        <td>foo faa</td>
        <td>faa fii</td>
        <td>foo faa</td>
        <td>faa fuu</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="2">
        <td>foo fuu</td>
        <td>fyy fuu</td>
        <td>foo foo</td>
        <td>fuu fii</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="3">
        <td>fuu faa</td>
        <td>fii fuu</td>
        <td>fuu fuu</td>
        <td>fyy fee</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="4">
        <td>foo foo</td>
        <td>fee faa</td>
        <td>fee fyy</td>
        <td>foo fuu</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Elements `td` in my example contains two words, but in my real case, elements `td` may contains more words. And `tr` elements may contains more 4 `td` childs.

I want select `tr` element(s) depending of innerText of its childs. I want be able to search multiple values.

Be example :

- if I search "fuu" and "foo" and "fii", the expected result of the xpath must be the elements `tr` with id 1 and 2.
- if I search "fuu" and "fii", the expected result of the xpath must be the elements `tr` with id 1 and 2 and 3.
- if I search only "fee", the expected result of the xpath must be the element `tr` with id 3 and 4.

I tried this :

```
//tr[*[contains(text(), 'fuu')] and *[contains(text(), 'foo')] and *[contains(text(), 'fii')]]
```

**Its work as expected** (http://xpather.com/Tdg5OGr2). But maybe it exist a more generic/proper solution, any idea someone ? 
If I want search by example ten words, the xpath will become really big x)

Comment: what about this? `//tr[contains(., 'fuu') and contains(., 'foo') and contains(., 'fii')]`

Comment: thanks for your answer. Its better yes, but doesn't exist a way like this : "//tr[something('fuu', 'foo', ... , 'fxx')]" or "//tr[something('fuu foo ... fxx')]"